# std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&) is private

Tags: c++, file, c++11

I'm attempting to save a complex object to a file, i'm overloading the << and >> operators within the complex object like this

```
class Data {
public:
    string name;
    double rating;

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Data& p)
{
    o << p.name << "\n";
    o << p.rating << "\n";
    return o;
}

friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& o, Data& p)
{
    o >> p.name >> p.rating;
    return o;
}
}
```

Then i'm using the operators to try and save an array of the object to a file.
Here is the class containing all file related methods:

```
class FileSave
{
public:
FileSave()
{
    openFile();
    load();
}

~FileSave()
{
    if(editm)
        outfile.close();
    else
        infile.close();
}

void openFile()
{
    if(editm)
        outfile.open("flatsave.elo", ios::out | ios::binary);
    else
        infile.open("flatsave.elo", ios::in | ios::binary);
}

void closeFile()
{
    if(editm)
        outfile.close();
    else
        infile.close();
}

void save()
{
    changemode(true);
    outfile << people << endl;
}

void load()
{
    changemode(false);
    for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        infile >> people[i];
    }
}

void changemode(bool editmode)
{
    if(editm != editmode)
    {
        closeFile();
        editm = editmode;
        openFile();
    }
}
private:
ofstream outfile;
ifstream infile;
bool editm = false;
};
```

Where people is the array of the Data object.

I've tried commenting out various bits but the error still occurs, other threads say that the header of my overload is wrong but i'm just copying letter for letter so i'm a bit confused by that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us the full error message.

Comment: You are trying to copy a stream (or `FileSave`, perhaps) somewhere.

Comment: Very vague question. I can guess at your problem and tell you what it is, but this is not a good post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of streams is invalid. When you use streams as members, you need to make sure your encapsulating object is not copyable.

If you add `FileSave(const FileSave&) = delete;` (or declare it as private and don't implement it - if you're working pre c++11), you will (I think) change the compilation error, to one about FileSave (as the code is probably making a copy of FileSave somewhere and that cannot be implemented because streams cannot be copied).

Instead of keeping stream objects in class scope, consider scoping stream objects in functions:

```
void demo_function()
{
    using namespace std;

    // "Where people is the array of the Data object"
    vector<Data> people;

    // load:
    ifstream in{ "flatsave.elo" };
    copy( istream_iterator<Data>{ in }, istream_iterator<Data>{},
        back_inserter(people) );

    // save:
    ofstream out{ "flatsave.elo" }; // will be flushed and saved
                                    // at end of scope
    copy( begin(people), end(people),
        ostream_iterator<Data>{ out, "\n" };

} // will flush out and save it and close both streams
```

Comment: Hey, i've tried this method and i'm getting an error in the in copy, it whines about the istream_iterator{} saying "missing template arguments before '{' token.

Answer (score 1):

Streams are not containers; they are flows of data. As such, they cannot be copied and, pre-C++11, the way that this is enforced is that their copy constructors are `private`.

Now, since your class `FileSave` contains two streams, that means `FileSave` cannot be copied either! The property is transitive. So, you'll have to ensure that you do not try to do that, *or* introduce some indirection around those members.